# How to use javascript:void(0) in a form action in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.1

As we all know `javascript:void(0)` is used to set action as undefined in simple html. But I need to use same thing in Laravel blade as stated below:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '#', 'class' => 'form-search', 'id'=>'search_form')) !!}
```

How to set form action as `javascript:void(0)` in the above code? I am using Laravel 5.1.

Comment: You have defined 'url' => '#'.  So no need to do that. laravel csrf form token also do the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '#', 'class' => 'form-search','id'=>'search_form')) !!}  
<!-- Content -->
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="function()" >
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And    In the Function()

```
javascript:void(0)
```